# How would "The dog is older than the child" be translated?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, adjetivos

Would the sentence, `The dog is older than the child` be translated as

> El perro es más viejo que el niño

or

> El perro es mayor que el niño

Answer (score 10):

I think both are technically correct, provided that the context (comparing ages) is understood, but I would definitely favor the first one ("El perro es más viejo que el niño"). There is certain ambiguity with the second one.

Take into account that the dictionary's entry for "[mayor](https://dle.rae.es/?id=OfcJXRh)" conveys (2nd and 3rd entries) that when applied to people this adjective can be used for describing or comparing **ages**.

> 2. adj. Dicho de una **persona**: Que excede en edad a otra. Hermana mayor. Marta es mayor que Juan.
> 3. adj. Dicho de una **persona**: Entrada en años, de edad avanzada. Hombre mayor.

The use of "mayor" when applied to animals could imply **size** and not necessarily age (meaning *is bigger* and not necessarily *is older*). That is why the context could be important when you are comparing both individuals. If the context is clear (comparing ages) I don't see any problems with the second option (meaning, I don't think that the second option is necessarily wrong, but I would favor the first one).

Regardless, take into account that in Spanish we don't usually say that "X es más viejo que Y" (as a translation of "X is older than Y"), but we use "tiene más años". So another way of saying the same would be

> El perro **tiene más años** que el niño.

Comment: Me pregunto si esto funcionaría también: El perro tiene más edad que el niño.